# Inserting object of two arrays into SQL Database using OPENJSON

Tags: c#, json, sql-server, t-sql, open-json

I wonder how can I put this JSON object, **consisting of two float numbers arrays**, into SQL Database Table:

```
{
    "Latitudes": [
    53.665084,
    53.665084,
    53.665184,
    53.665284
    ],
    "Longitudes":[
    17.342853,
    17.342953,
    17.343053,
    17.343153
    ]
}
```

Table has 3 columns: CoordID, Latitude, Longitude (CoordID is auto-incremented).
I would like to put each pair of those tables ( [0],[0] / [1][1] etc. ) as one row in table. ***So with this object, it would be 4 rows.***

Here is the code which doesn't work as I expect - it just puts nulls in place of "Longitude" and "Latitude" columns and it only creates ONE ROW... (Instead of 4 rows):

```
declare @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @json=
'{
    "Latitudes": [
    53.665084,
    53.665084,
    53.665184,
    53.665284
    ],
    "Longitudes":[
    17.342853,
    17.342953,
    17.343053,
    17.343153
    ]
}'

insert into dbo.Coords(
[Latitude],[Longitude])
select Latitude, Longitude from OPENJSON(@json)
WITH(
Latitude FLOAT '$."Latitudes"',
Longitude FLOAT '$."Longitudes"')
```

P.S
OPENJSON() function works from version 2016 of SQL Server or on the Azure SQL Database. Just in case if anyone would try to run this in SSMS 2014 i.e ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve your data using only `OPENJSON()`. 
The important part here is the fact, that when `OPENJSON()` parses a `JSON` array, 
the function [returns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#return-value) the indexes of the elements in this array as keys, so you can join result on these indexes.

T-SQL:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @json=
'{
    "Latitudes": [
    53.665084,
    53.665084,
    53.665184,
    53.665284
    ],
    "Longitudes": [
    17.342853,
    17.342953,
    17.343053,
    17.343153
    ]
}'

--INSERT INTO dbo.Coords([Latitude], [Longitude])
SELECT j1.[value], j2.[value]
FROM 
   OPENJSON(@json, '$.Latitudes') j1,
   OPENJSON(@json, '$.Longitudes') j2
WHERE j1.[key] = j2.[key]
```

Output (from `SELECT` statement):

```
---------------------
value       value
---------------------
53.665084   17.342853
53.665084   17.342953
53.665184   17.343053
53.665284   17.343153
```

Comment: I knew there was a way to do this when I was looking at it yesterday but, for the life of me, I couldn't get it sorted. Sticking this in my notes. Thanks for this!

Comment: @Zhorov WORKING LIKE A CHARM. Exactly what I needed - huge Thank You! I was even able to combine it with object consisting of 3 addition key:value pairs.

Comment: @KamilTurowski Glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

Using `JSON_QUERY` to parse array:

```
declare @json NVARCHAR(MAX) =
'{
    "Latitudes": [
    53.665084,
    53.665084,
    53.665184,
    53.665284
    ],
    "Longitudes":[
    17.342853,
    17.342953,
    17.343053,
    17.343153
    ]
}';

WITH cte1 AS (
  select A.value Latitude, [key] AS rn from OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(@json,'$.Latitudes')) A
), cte2 AS (
  select A.value Longitude,[key] AS rn from OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(@json,'$.Longitudes')) A
)
--insert into dbo.Coords([Latitude],[Longitude])
SELECT Latitude, Longitude
FROM cte1
JOIN cte2
  ON cte1.rn = cte2.rn;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6966174879fc13f09eb0f8378b14f611)**

Comment: `rn` should be`ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [key]) AS rn`, as otherwise the return order of the rows is undocumented and subject to change.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thanks for hint, now it is fully deterministic :)

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Actually I don't need row_number at all.

Comment: My first thought was a CROSS APPLY, but on a side-by-side comparison, yours was only 7% of the batch while mine was 93%... +1